# PHP check current time

Tags: php

im having a little problem about checking the current time on submitted time

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Hong_Kong');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

i want to to it like this

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) {


if (date (H)< 1pm) {
/* get the time difference or */ echo " you're late $late ";
// do something  }
else if (date (H) < 4pm) {
/get the time difference or */ echo " you're late $late ";
// do something }
else if (date (H) < 7pm {
/* get the time difference or */echo " you're late $late ";
// do something }
}
```

but i dont know how to compute the `$late`
and `$late` is to know how many hours/minute the submitted time

Comment: What should `$late` be? How many hours/minutes they're late?

Comment: yes sir, ill edit it now

Comment: I guess these are intervals (1pm, 4pm, 7pm), but when is the user not late?

Comment: if user is not late ill just automatically redirect them to the sumbitted timeslot but the important here is to get the late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to create a dateobject from the given time, and use `new DateTime()` to compare against.

```
$now = new DateTime();
if ($now->format("H:i") > "13:00") {
    $deadline = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", "13:00");
    $diff = $now->diff($deadline);
    echo "You are ".$diff->h." hours and ".$diff->i." minutes late";
}
```

If you submit the form at 14:04, the above snippet would output

> You are 1 hours and 4 minutes late

Comment: Why don't you try it? ;-) A jsfiddle won't work though, PHP != JS

Comment: Then you need to update the question with the HTML form and the PHP you're using here.

Comment: hi im trying to insert the $diff into the db `time_in(time)` but im getting this error (Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string )

Comment: You'll need to use `$diff->format()` and specify the format you'll be inserting. What type of column is it you're inserting to?

Comment: im trying to put this in my query `$diff ->h` or `$diff ->i`  but what only inserted is only hour/minute but not in time format

Answer (score 0):

depents on what you are trying to show... Im assuming here you want to show the difference between two times (datetimes). You can do it like this:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2071-02-14 02:28:30');
$datetime2 = new DateTime();
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo "\ndate1: " . $datetime1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
echo "\ndate2: " . $datetime2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
echo "\ndiff: " . $interval->format('%R%H hours');
```

check out the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) for formating the interval output.

if you want to just show based on the time when the request was submitted you can simply use

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$hours = $datetime->format('H');
```

and then use the $hours variable to decide what to do. hope that helps.
a bit more documentation on the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

Comment: i want to show time time current time using my timezone but when i click the submit button it will show the late like example i click it at 1:05 then a display of youre late 00:05:00 something like that

Comment: and also i need to show the minute your code only shows time

Comment: @JustAngelo you do know i gave you a link with all the parameters for format interval...
$interval->format('%H:%I:%S');  for your case that you described in the comment, but is not mentioned at all in your original question

Comment: im implimenting this but im still having some error